# org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool - XML Parsing Error

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on

Currently i am working on SAML IDP intitated SSO implementation.

Here are steps what i have done.

1. If user session doesn't exists, calling the login URL of IDP server(One login).

```java
    URL serviceUrl = new URL("https://lechm-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/74697012");
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(serviceUrl.toString());
```

2. After login, IDP is sending the SAML response to the redirect URL

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/saml/auth"})
public String authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    MyUser myUser = null;
    if(null != request.getParameter("SAMLResponse")) {
        myUser = userService.createUserFromResponse(request.getParameter("SAMLResponse"));
    }

    return "authenticate...!  ";
}
```

3. In the user service logic for parsing the SAML response

```java
@Override
public MyUser createUserFromResponse(String samlResponse) throws 
          ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
        IOException, UnmarshallingException, XMLParserException {



    Response resp = null;
    if (samlResponse != null) {

        Document document = null;
        try {
            DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

            BasicParserPool basicParserPool = new BasicParserPool();
            basicParserPool.setNamespaceAware(true);
            Reader reader = new StringReader(samlResponse);
            document = basicParserPool.parse(reader);  // here i am getting SAXParseException

        } catch (ConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

        UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(element);
        XMLObject responseXmlObj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);

        resp = (Response) responseXmlObj;

        createUserJSONFromAttributes(resp);
    }
    LOG.debug(">>>>>>> SAML Response : MyUser Object  >>>>> :  " + myUser.toString());
    return myUser;
}
```

Here, on parsing the SAML response i am facing SAXParseException.

```java
23:59:53 ERROR org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool - XML Parsing Error
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool$DocumentBuilderProxy.parse(BasicParserPool.java:690)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.parse(BasicParserPool.java:233)
```

Please let me know what i have done wrong.. Please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the SAML response you are attempting to parse as XML?  Is it really the string `"authenticate...!  "` or is it something else you've chosen to omit from your question?

Comment: The response I got from the idp is in byte code. Which is of long byte example : bshdhebhdjhdunruggrujevgduk3bctydiwkbsvvgsjkbwvhhnbegaikwbeguskbvysqopqbev. And the string authenticate...! Is just for return expected for the method.

Comment: That string you give as an example isn't XML (I don't know what it is), so you can't parse it as if it were XML.

Comment: I am getting the same error for the XML parsing.  The xml (after decoding the response) starts with  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'  See the characters at the start? It is breaking the xml parsing.  I suspect it is being sent by the php script

Comment: so the junk/extra characters do not show after I post the comment.  In front of the <?xml we see two extra non ASCII characters when we decode the response.